# Using CASE statement with Alias to create another column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create new column called "Size" based on my long CASE statement. I used "Number of items" as the Alias.

Would you be able to help me please?

My CASE statement is:

```
  CASE WHEN (dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext LIKE 'Run%') THEN (CEILING(dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered / 4)) WHEN dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext LIKE 'Pure' THEN (CEILING(dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered / 4)) 
                     WHEN dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext LIKE 'Team%' THEN (CEILING(dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered / 4)) ELSE dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered END AS NumberofItems
```

and the new column I am trying to add is when the Number of items is < 5, then display "car" else display "van". That column should have an alias "SIZE"

I am stuck on that.

Comment: Sounds like you need to separate case statements.  You are doing a lot in the CASE, maybe convert to using temp table or sub select.  It will make it easier to read and you will only have to do your calculations once, then just do the CASE on that calculated columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to nest this in another `CASE`.

```
CASE WHEN
        CASE 
            WHEN dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext LIKE 'Run%'
                THEN (CEILING(dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered / 4)) 
            WHEN dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext LIKE 'Pure' 
                THEN (CEILING(dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered / 4)) 
            WHEN dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext LIKE 'Team%' 
                THEN (CEILING(dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered / 4)) 
            ELSE dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered 
        END 
      < 5 
      THEN 'Car'
      ELSE 'VAN'
END as NewCol
```

Or, another method would be to use a `CTE`.

```
;with cte as(
select *,
        CASE 
            WHEN dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext LIKE 'Run%'
                THEN (CEILING(dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered / 4)) 
            WHEN dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext LIKE 'Pure' 
                THEN (CEILING(dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered / 4)) 
            WHEN dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext LIKE 'Team%' 
                THEN (CEILING(dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered / 4)) 
            ELSE dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered 
        END as NumberofItems
from ItemSpecs)

select *,
    case when NumberofItems < 5 then 'car' else 'van' end as NewCol
from cte
```

Or inline as a derived table

```
select
   col1,
   col2,
   case when NumberofItems < 5 then 'car' else 'van' end
from
    (select *,
            CASE 
                WHEN dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext LIKE 'Run%'
                    THEN (CEILING(dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered / 4)) 
                WHEN dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext LIKE 'Pure' 
                    THEN (CEILING(dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered / 4)) 
                WHEN dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext LIKE 'Team%' 
                    THEN (CEILING(dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered / 4)) 
                ELSE dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered 
            END as NumberofItems
    from ItemSpecs) x
```